# How to keep session open while detecting over multiple images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, object-detection

I think when running the "inference for single image" function in the tensorflow research folder, that tensorflow creates a session every time it detects (using this code). How do I keep the session open and just inference another image with it?

I've only tried this 'single inference' function and looped it across a directory of images. It has been rather slow, and much slower than a 'while true: cv2 = image capture' video stream detection using the same model.

```
def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict
```

The code will successfully loop over a list of images, however it is slow. I suspect it is because tensorflow is reloading the same model over and over again as it instantiates a new session into the GPU every loop. So how to keep the session open between loops?

Comment: move `with tf.Session() as sess:` outside the function.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori testing now thanks :) I feel stupid :/

Answer (score 0):

So I've shifted the:

```
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
```

To instantiate outside of the loop, but honestly the performance isn't that much better, running on a gtx1080 it's still taking over a second to process a 352x288 image using ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 model which is supposed to be quite fast.

Does anyone have any advice as to loading multiple images in parallel for batch image processing?

The strange part is that it's using over 7.8GB of GPU space to process each image, which I think is probably too high and it's allocating all available space but not actually using it.

NVIDIA-SMI output:

```
Thu Jan 31 11:33:53 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 14%   54C    P2    42W / 180W |   7879MiB /  8111MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

As shown, the session is using basically 7.5GB (shown in PIDs) however it's only working at 42W power - so this doesn't seem to indicate a full load.

Thoughts?

All images are static shapes, so perhaps if I can increase the tensor size to allocate multiple images it would work?